# What to do about compiler warnings

Tags: java

```
 List<RPC> mrpcs = new ArrayList<>();
 rpcs = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM RPC").list();
```

This gives me a warning. The Intellij's solution is to change `List<RPC>` to `List`

I want to avoid warnings on my program.

Should I keep like this or change it?

Comment: side note: the variable name is `mrpcs` or `rpcs`?

Comment: Which Java Version do you use?

Comment: In which line you get the warning?

Comment: `rpcs` it's a typo. I use Java 1.8 and Hibernate. I get a typo in the second line. Unchecked assignment List<RPC> to List

Comment: `List<RPC> mrpcs = new ArrayList<>();` because you initialze the list and override it in the second line